# Poor lookup aggregation performance

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two collections

Posts:

```
{
    "_Id": "1",
    "_PostTypeId": "1",
    "_AcceptedAnswerId": "192",
    "_CreationDate": "2012-02-08T20:02:48.790",
    "_Score": "10",
    ...
    "_OwnerUserId": "6",
    ...
},
...
```

and users:

```
{
    "_Id": "1",
    "_Reputation": "101",
    "_CreationDate": "2012-02-08T19:45:13.447",
    "_DisplayName": "Geoff Dalgas",
    ...
    "_AccountId": "2"
},
...
```

and I want to find users who write between 5 and 15 posts.
This is how my query looks like:

```
db.posts.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "users", 
            localField: "_OwnerUserId",
            foreignField: "_AccountId", 
            as: "X"
        }
    },  
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$X._AccountId", 
            posts: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },   
    {
        $match : {posts: {$gte: 5, $lte: 15}}
    },  
    {
        $sort: {posts: -1 }
    },
    {
        $project : {posts: 1}
    }
])
```

and it works terrible slow. For 6k users and 10k posts it tooks over 40 seconds to get response while in relational database I get response in a split second.
Where's the problem? I'm just getting started with mongodb and it's quite possible that I messed up this query.

Comment: you're attempting to relate data using a non-relational database and then noting that it takes more time than a relational database?  You do need to make sure there is an index on _accountId field.

Comment: @bauman.space That's where the problem was. Now it takes only 700 ms!

Comment: marked up an answer with the link to the reason behind why it works.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

from https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

> foreignField  Specifies the field from the documents in the from
>   collection. **$lookup performs an equality match on the foreignField** to
>   the localField from the input documents. If a document in the from
>   collection does not contain the foreignField, the $lookup treats the
>   value as null for matching purposes.

This will be performed the same as any other query.

If you don't have an index on the field _AccountId, it will do a full tablescan query for each one of the 10,000 posts.  The bulk of the time will be spent in that tablescan.

```
db.users.ensureIndex("_AccountId", 1)
```

speeds up the process so it's doing 10,000 index hits instead of 10,000 table scans.

Comment: what is your suggestion? "lookup" vs "copy & update all record on edit"

Comment: I needed this. Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

In addition to *bauman.space*'s suggestion to put an index on the *_accountId* field (which is critical), you should also do your *$match* stage as early as possible in the aggregation pipeline (i.e. as the first stage). Even though it won't use any indexes (unless you index the posts field), it will filter the result set before doing the *$lookup* (join) stage.

The reason why your query is terribly slow is that for **every** post, it is doing a non-indexed lookup (sequential read) for every user. That's around 60m reads!

Check out the *Pipeline Optimization* section of the [MongoDB Aggregation Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/).

Comment: Yes, bauman.space's tip was really helpful. Regarding the $match location in query what can I change in this specific query? I can's see how to improve my query but I'm not familiar with mongodb at all.

Comment: Just move the $match section to the first position in the array you are passing to the aggregate function (i.e. above the $lookup section). The aggregate works like a pipeline, so the results from one step are passed to the next, like a progressive filtering process. By putting the $match section before the $lookup section, you are reducing the number of lookups to only those records that get through the $match step.

Comment: I'd be interested to know how much each change improved the performance of your query.

Comment: But in my case $match use `posts` variable declared in $group so changing stages order wouldn't work. If I move $match before $group I get empty results

Comment: The way to look at it is you are currently doing a user lookup for every post which is unnecessary. You really only want to lookup each user once. So I would do it in the order of: $group (by _OwnerUserId), $match, $lookup, then $sort/$project. It should dramatically reduce the number of reads against the user table.

Comment: Thanks. I had a similar case and declaring two $match resulted in a huge improvement.

Answer (score 5):

First use `$match` then `$lookup`. `$match` filter the rows need to be examined to `$lookup`. It's efficient.

Comment: There is a previous answer with your exact same answer !

Answer (score 1):

as long as you're going to group by user `_AccountId`, you should do the `$group` first by `_OwnerUserId` then lookup only after filtering accounts having `10<postsCount<15` this will reduce lookups:

```js
db.posts.aggregate([{
    $group: {
      _id: "$_OwnerUserId",
      postsCount: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      posts: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      } //if you need to keep original posts data
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      postsCount: {
        $gte: 5,
        $lte: 15
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "_AccountId",
      as: "X"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$X"
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      postsCount: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      postsCount: 1,
      X: 1
    }
  }
])
```