# NodeJs mongoose performance slow when compared with mongo shell or robo3t performance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am running a query that prints around 300 results using aggregate.

The query is super fast when executed in robo3t/mongo shell but super slow when done using mongoose in NodeJs.

Tried finding for an answer, landed on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57789926/mongodb-nodejs-native-drivermongodb-vs-mongo-shell-performance) tried setting `DBQuery.shellBatchSize = 500000;` but difference b/w two queries is still around 7-8 secs

Also, updated the mongoose and mongodb version to the latest one today itself.

here is the query:

```
db.getCollection('fixed_activities').aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "city",
        localField: "activity_city",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "activity_location"
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "rate_sheet_activity_prices",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "act_id",
        as: "rate_sheets"
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "organizations",
        localField: "rate_sheets.rate_sheet_id",
        foreignField: "rate_sheets.rate_sheet_id",
        as: "org_id"
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "images",
        localField: "activity_image",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "activity_image"
      }
    },
    { $match: { org_id: { $exists: true, $not: { $size: 0 } } } }
  ])
```

Comment: lets try creating some index on db.

Comment: I don't think that can help reduce time on server-side queries as indexes for mongo shell and mongo on the Node are the same.  Or if they do use indexes in a different manner then it's a different story but I don't think this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my solution was to switch from mongoose to the native mongodb controller in nodejs.

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.3/installation-guide/installation-guide/

Comment: will try and let you know